# How to use swift-4 Promises then, done, catch and other blocks

Tags: ios, swift, swift4, promisekit

I would like to learn about promises in swift-4. How to use multiple then statements and done, catch blocks.

Here I am trying to get the value from the promise. But I'm getting errors. Could someone help me to understand promises?

Here is my code.

```
import UIKit
import PromiseKit

struct User {
    var firstname : String?
    var lastname  : String?
}

struct APIError {
    var message : String?
}

class ViewController : UIViewController {
    override func viewDidLoad() {
        super.viewDidLoad()
        let userPromise : Promise = self.getUserDetails()
        userPromise.then { user -> Void in
            //print(user.f)
        }
    }

    func getUserDetails()->Promise<User> {
        return Promise<User> { resolve in
            let user  = User(firstname: "Scot", lastname: "dem")
            if ((user.firstname?.count) != nil) {
                resolve.fulfill(user)
            } else {
                let error = APIError(message: "User not valid")
                resolve.reject(error as! Error)
            }
        }
    }
}
```

Once I get the user details I want to make a full name, uppercase promises which are dependent on userPromise.

I would like to use multiple then, done, finally blocks. Just want to understand usage.

> Why I'm getting an error here when we use userPromise.then { user -> Void in

what should I give inside the block

Comment: What errors? Where? Please [edit] your question to be clear and precise.

Answer (score 19):

In PromiseKit 6, `then` can no longer return `Void`. This is mainly due to the tuplegate issue in Swift 4.

Quote from [PromieKit 6 Release News](http://promisekit.org/news/2018/02/PromiseKit-6.0-Released/)

> With PromiseKit our `then` did multiple things, and we relied on Swift
>   to infer the correct `then` from context. However with multiple line
>   `then`s it would fail to do this, and instead of telling you that the
>   situation was ambiguous it would invent some other error. Often the
>   dreaded `cannot convert T to AnyPromise`. We have a troubleshooting
>   guide to combat this but I believe in tools that just work, and when
>   you spend 4 years waiting for Swift to fix the issue and Swift doesn’t
>   fix the issue, what do you do? We chose to find a solution at the
>   higher level.
>
> So we split `then` into `then`, `done` and `map`.
>
> - `then` is fed the previous promise value and requires you return a promise.
> - `done` is fed the previous promise value and returns a Void promise (which is 80% of chain usage)
> - `map` is fed the previous promise value and requires you return a non-promise, ie. a value.

---

**Hence `.then { (user) -> Void in` is no longer valid and that's why you're getting an error.**
It's now designed to return a `Thenable` like so:

```
userPromise.then { user -> Promise<User> in
    //return yet another promise
}
```

**The `.then` that used to return `Void` is now it's own `.done`.**
i.e:

```
userPromise.done { (user) in
    print(user)
}
```

---

#### So when you mix 'em up:

We get:

```
userPromise
    .then { (user) -> Promise<User> in
        //return another Promise
        return self.uppercasePromise(on: user)
    }
    .done { (user) in
        /*
         Depending on your sequence, no more promises are left 
         and you should have a matured user object by now
         */
        print(user)
    }
    .catch { (error) in
        print(error)
    }
    .finally {
        print("finally")
    }

func uppercasePromise(on user: User) -> Promise<User> {
    /*
     Didn't understand your statement but do whatever you meant when you said:

     "Once I get the user details I want to make a full name, "
     uppercase promises which are dependent on userPromise."
     */
    return Promise { seal in
        seal.fulfill(user)
    }
}
```

Comment: OMG :), I did misunderstand that as your comment. Sorry for that, Thank you 'BRO'